# Erratic behavior from beamer goto and return buttons

Tags: beamer, hyperref

The code below is generating erratic behavior in two respects:
     1) The line `\returnFrom{fourthGoto}{fourthReturn}` creates a `beamerreturnbutton` that says `Frame #2`.   All of the other buttons correctly return a button saying `Frame #1`.
     2) The only difference between the `returnFrom` and `altReturnFrom` macros is that the latter does not include the word `Frame` inside the `beamerreturnbutton`.  It's hard to imagine why this difference should matter.   Yet the last button predictably behaves unpredictably. Clicking back and forth on the buttons labeled -> #6  and <-#6, sometimes it works, but eventually,click on the button on Frame #6  takes me back to the first line of the first frame, rather than the sixth line of that frame.    I haven't been able to generate this error from the return button labeled #5 on frame #5.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{c@insideAList}{\newcounter{insideAList}}{}
\let\beamer@cramped\relax% just because
\let\c@insideAList\@listdepth % make a latex counter version
\makeatother
\def\condHyperTarget#1{
    \ifthenelse{\theinsideAList=0}
        {\hypertarget<.(1)>{#1}{} }
        {\hypertarget<.>{#1}{} }}
\def\pointTo#1#2{
    \label{pointToLoc#1}
    \condHyperTarget{#1}
    \hyperlink{#2}{\beamergotobutton{\#\ref{returnFromLoc#2} }}}
\def\returnFrom#1#2{
    \label{returnFromLoc#1}
    \condHyperTarget{#1}\hyperlink{#2}{\beamerreturnbutton{Frame \#\ref{pointToLoc#2}}}}
\def\altReturnFrom#1#2{
    \label{returnFromLoc#1}
    \condHyperTarget{#1}\hyperlink{#2}{\beamerreturnbutton{\#\ref{pointToLoc#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
First line   \\
\pause
Second line \\
\pause
Third line
\pointTo{firstReturn}{firstGoto}
\pause
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First item OUTER
    \item Second item OUTER
    \pointTo{secondReturn}{secondGoto}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item First item INNER
        \item Second item INNER
            \pointTo{thirdReturn}{thirdGoto}
            \pause
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
Fourth line   \\
\pause
Fifth line
\pointTo{fourthReturn}{fourthGoto} \\
\pause
Sixth Line
\pointTo{fifthReturn}{fifthGoto}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 2\\
\returnFrom{firstGoto}{firstReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame} \begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 3\\
\returnFrom{secondGoto}{secondReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame} \begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 4\\
\returnFrom{thirdGoto}{thirdReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame} \begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 5\\
\returnFrom{fourthGoto}{fourthReturn}
\end{frame} \begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 6\\
\altReturnFrom{fifthGoto}{fifthReturn}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need frame number in the text of your buttons?

Comment: I include the frame numbers because I (and others) sometimes work off hard-copies of my slide deck.      Without the numbers, really the only way to navigate the deck is on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 2

The second problem is easy to solve. You are using `\ref` in your macros, which will produce a link, but just for the number. With a viwer which show the target of a link, if the mouse hovers over it, this can be seen (Gehe zu Seite = Goto Page):

[image]
[image]

This applies to both, `\returnFrom` and `\altReturnFrom`. But with the latter you're less likely to hit the number.

**Solution: just repalce `\ref` with `\ref*`.**
The latter only gives out the number without making it a link.

### Problem 1

The first problem is caused by using `\label`, which refers to the number of the last structure element (frame, equation, numbered item, ...). In your case it's item 2 of the `enumerate` environmet. To test this, you can replace
`enumerate` with `itemize`.

Unfortuneately, to my knowlegde, there is no way build into `beamer` to reference the frame number. It can be done, but requires quite some programming.

**Edit:**

Since you have a good reason for having the frame number in the buttons, here is a solution for this. It produces an additional auxiliary file `\jobname.fno`.

You need to run LaTeX twice for this to work. But you don't need to change the source after `\begin{document}` (with the exception of `\altReturnFrom`, which I didn't implement here).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@cramped\relax% just because

\newcommand*{\refframenumber}[1]{%
    \csname #1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\labelframenumber}[1]{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\@writefile{fno}{\string\expandafter\string\def\string\csname\space#1\string\endcsname{\insertframenumber}}}%
}

\def\condHyperTarget#1{%
    \ifnum\@listdepth=0\relax
        \hypertarget<.(1)>{#1}{}%
    \else
        \hypertarget<.>{#1}{}%
    \fi
}%
\def\pointTo#1#2{%
    \labelframenumber{pointToLoc#1}%
    \condHyperTarget{#1}%
    \hyperlink{#2}{\beamergotobutton{\#\refframenumber{returnFromLoc#2} }}}
\def\returnFrom#1#2{%
    \labelframenumber{returnFromLoc#1}%
    \condHyperTarget{#1}%
    \hyperlink{#2}{\beamerreturnbutton{Frame \#\refframenumber{pointToLoc#2}}}}

% read .fno file
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.fno}{}{}%
}

% open .fno file for LaTeX to write
\AtEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw\newwrite\tf@fno
        \immediate\openout\tf@fno\jobname.fno\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
First line   \\
\pause
Second line \\
\pause
Third line
\pointTo{firstReturn}{firstGoto}
\pause
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First item OUTER
    \item Second item OUTER
    \pointTo{secondReturn}{secondGoto}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item First item INNER
        \item Second item INNER
            \pointTo{thirdReturn}{thirdGoto}
            \pause
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
Fourth line   \\
\pause
Fifth line
\pointTo{fourthReturn}{fourthGoto} \\
\pause
Sixth Line
\pointTo{fifthReturn}{fifthGoto}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 2\\
\returnFrom{firstGoto}{firstReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 3\\
\returnFrom{secondGoto}{secondReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 4\\
\returnFrom{thirdGoto}{thirdReturn}
$\empty$\\%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 5\\
\returnFrom{fourthGoto}{fourthReturn}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
Frame 6\\
\returnFrom{fifthGoto}{fifthReturn}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Mike.   No longer mystifying.    I guess I'll have to work around  problem #1 by using itemize instead of enumerate when I need to add a button, and then manually insert numbers.

Comment: @LeoSimon I added an example for referencing frame numbers, see edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed, @Mike for all that work.    It's very daunting.  One question:  you're not using the `\ref*` format here, yet it seems to be the case that whereever I put the cursor in the button it works.    Is the construction you are using an alternative to `\ref*`.     Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon `\labelframenumber` and `\refframenumber` are pimitive compared to `\label` and `\ref`. They don't produce links (this is done with `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` in your macros), they just store/retrieve the frame number.